# Complex queryset with annotate across different models

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

I'm using Django 1.6 and have following models (a bit simplified for readability):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Room(models.Model):
    max_persons = models.SmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Stay(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    STAY_TYPE = (
        (1, 'Type 1'),
        (2, 'Type 2'),
        (3, 'Type 3'),
    )
    stay_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STAY_TYPE)

class Hospitalization(models.Model):
    stay = models.ForeignKey(Stay)
    date_in = models.DateField()
    date_out = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
```

With a `queryset` (in a manager), I'd like to obtain all the available rooms for a given date, i.e. where `max_persons` isn't met.

So far, I've tried to play around with `Q` and things like `Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out__lt="2014-04-25")` but I'm not able to figure out the `max_persons` comparison.

Would you have any idea?

**EDIT**

The count of Person objects related to each room is representative of the number of people in that room.

Therefore, as per Karl's suggestions below, I've tried to play around with:

- `Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out__lte="2014-04-25").annotate(num_persons=hospitalization_set__stay__person.Count()).exclude(num_persons__lte=max_persons)`

  - Yields `NameError: name 'hospitalization_set__stay__person' is not defined`
- `Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out__lte="2014-04-25").annotate(num_persons=Count('hospitalization_set__stay__person')).exclude(num_persons__lte=max_persons)`

  - Yields `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'hospitalization_set' into field.`
- `Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out__lte="2014-04-25").annotate(num_persons=Count('hospitalization__stay__person')).exclude(num_persons__lte=F('max_persons'))`

  - Yields nothing (`[]`), while I'm expecting at least three results according to my current DB.
  - When removing `.exclude()`, I still get no results. It looks like the `.annotate()` I'm using is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that something similar to `Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out="2014-04-25", max_persons__lt=x)` should do the trick. Remember that you can have multiple declarations in a filter operation, and that you can also chain both exclusions and filters. This doesn't add to database activity; `queryset` filters and the like are only executed when the `queryset` itself is evaluated. See [The Django Docs on making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters).

**EDIT:**
This actually turned out to be slightly more complicated than I first thought, but I believe I have worked it out (after importing your model declarations and having a shell session!)

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(DATE FILTERING HERE).annotate(num_persons=Count('hospitalization__room__id')).filter(num_persons__lt=F('max_persons')).count()
```

Will give you the number of rooms in which `num_persons` (our annotated variable above) is less than `max_persons`, with the date filtering occurring beforehand.

Remember to include the required imports:
`from django.db.models import Count`
`from django.db.models import F`

Comment: Hmm, but I should get 'x' using the same queryset somehow, isn't it? How would that work?

Comment: That is dependent on what value x should have. I presume that the count of Person objects related to each room will be representative of the number of people in that room? In that case you would annotate the queryset with the count of those relationships. I would personally modify your model declarations to include a simpler relationship between 'Person' and 'Room'. As it is, I believe something similar to this could work (untested):

Room.objects.filter(hospitalization__date_out="2014-04-25").annotate(num_persons=Hospitalization_set__stay__person.Count()).exclude(num_persons__lte=max_persons)

Comment: Correct, the count of Person objects related to each room will be representative of the number of people in that room. I've been thinking about modifying my models in order to simplify things, but the problem is that in one Stay, the Room of the Person can change; I'll add to my question. I've tried your query (thanks for the help!!), but couldn't get it to work. I seem unable to use the reverse `hospitalization_set` in the query. I've tried to fix that by adding the path as a parameter to the aggregate Count function (not sure whether that's OK), but now I cannot do the  'exclude' comparison.

Comment: (Fixed the `exclude` comparison using F objects - adjusted the question)

Comment: I completely forgot to add a comment here @SaeX... Please see the above edit to my answer. That query should give you the response you're looking for, without having to modify your model declarations.

Comment: Thanks Karl, your edits miss the exact part I'm still struggling with, i.e. the `DATE FILTERING HERE`. But you did answer my main question, which is how to get `num_persons` and compare with `max_persons`. Thanks for that! I'll open a different question after playing with it some more.